# PDF : Can't find image to compress

Tags: c#, itext

I have a PDF with a huge image that I want to compress (almost 1080p for a 100x100 display).
Usually, I use this code to compress pictures.
For this PDF, it can't find any picture. I've looked at each `xobject.Get(name)` , trying too find a big picture with no results.
Where can I find this picture or which method can I use to compress it ?

```
//Bind a reader to our large PDF
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bt);
using (MemoryStream msOut = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Bind a stamper to the file and our reader
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, msOut))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(i);
            //Get the xobject structure
            PdfDictionary resources = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(page.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES));
            PdfDictionary xobject = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(resources.Get(PdfName.XOBJECT));
            if (xobject != null)
            {
                PdfObject obj;
                //Loop through each key
                foreach (PdfName name in xobject.Keys)
                {
                    obj = xobject.Get(name);
                    if (obj.IsIndirect())
                    {
                        //Get the current key as a PDF object
                        PdfDictionary imgObject = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj);
                        //See if its an image
                        if (imgObject != null && imgObject.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.IMAGE))
                        {
                            //NOTE: There's a bunch of different types of filters, I'm only handing the simplest one here which is basically raw JPG, you'll have to research others
                            if (imgObject.Get(PdfName.FILTER).Equals(PdfName.DCTDECODE))
                            {
                                byte[] oldBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)imgObject);
                                byte[] newBytes;
                                using (MemoryStream sourceMS = new MemoryStream(oldBytes))
                                using (System.Drawing.Image oldImage = Bitmap.FromStream(sourceMS))
                                    newBytes = ConvertImageToBytes(oldImage);

                                iTextSharp.text.Image compressedImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(newBytes);
                                PdfReader.KillIndirect(obj);
                                stamper.Writer.AddDirectImageSimple(compressedImage, (PRIndirectReference)obj);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return msOut.ToArray();
}
```

By the way, I've alread tried to use `stamper.SetFullCompression` or `reader.SetPageContent(1, reader.GetPageContent(1), PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION);. Size remains almost the same.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is caused by an image? Maybe it's a large font. Maybe it's a color profile. Or maybe the PDF has `/PieceInfo` information (will be deprecated in 2.0) that consumes plenty of file size. You will have to share the PDF if you want a clear answer.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Unfortunately, I can't share it. It's one of my client's invoice with personnal data. I'm sure that it is this picture as my client's PDF were very light before he add it (less than 100Kb). Now, they weights more than 1.2Mb.

Comment: We've seen the same happening with people who undeliberately added a large number of embedded fonts. By the way: since you work for a customer, you probably need a commercial license for iText. If you have a commercial license, you can share documents with our tech support team under NDA.

Comment: Your code only looks at the **immediate** bitmap image **resources of the page**. But a bitmap image might also appear on a page because it is drawn on a form XObject, or a pattern template, or even on a Type 3 font character. Furthermore, your code only looks for JPG bitmap images (a comment in it even says so), but there also are other bitmap image formats. Without the PDF it is difficult to help you any further. As your client creates the files in question, you might ask him to generate a similar PDF with dummy data for analysis by externals.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks ! I'll do that !